# Maintain insertion order for equal elements in std::multiset

Tags: c++, stl, multiset, strict-weak-ordering

I have a std::multiset of sorted custom objects. Two equal objects (based on the < operator) in the multiset may contain some fields which are not equal. In that case I need to maintain the order of insertion of objects in the multiset<>.

I know this is not an issue if I am using C++11 but we are not at this point.

Another solution I saw uses a timestamp field in the class using `<ctime>` but that gives a resolution of 1 second. If I have 2 insertions in the same second then I cant use the timestamp in the compare operation. We are not / can not using boost::chrono on this project.

Is there another way I can use to ensure insertion order is maintained?

Comment: It is be possible to use `s.upper_bound' to find the insertion point immediately after all of the other equivalent entries.  What I don't know is if an implementation of std::set could re-order it due to other later operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a wild idea: As @Jerry suggests, maintain a counter. Since the pair of object and counter is unique, we can now use a set (ordered lexicographically). Then we use `lower_bound` to find the insertion point and compute the next counter value:

```
unsigned int const uimax = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();

typedef std::set<std::pair<T, unsigned int>> pair_set;

void counted_insert(pair_set & s, T const & t)
{
    pair_set::iterator it = s.lower_bound(std::make_pair(t, uimax));

    if (it == s.begin() || !(*--it == t))
    {
        s.insert(it, std::make_pair(t, 0));
    }
    else
    {
        s.insert(it, std::make_pair(t, it->first + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things.  1) You meant `it == s.end()` and 2) you should use equivalence, not equality for the comparison.  Actually, upon second consideration, I don't think lower_bound will return what you want in this case.  lower_bound returns the first element that is not less than the requested element.  Since (t,0) is less than (t, uimax), it will only insert the first time, and fail afterwards.

Comment: @DaveS: You're right, I got ahead of myself. I think now it's better.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use a counter that's incremented every time you insert a new item, and use that as the last field to compare when you do an insertion. In a typical case, you'll want to make the counter a static member of the class managing the collection.

Comment: In fact, the counter could be computed from the last value in the multiset (or set in that case)...

Comment: @KerrekSB: If you have a composite key, there's no guarantee the last value has the greatest counter.